# Selecting particular columns crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have got a data something like this

```
var data = [
{name: "name1",age:100,gender: m ,someotherfiled: ""},
{name: "name2",age:101 ,gender: f,someotherfiled: ""}
]
```

I want select only two fields something like this

```
[
    {name: "name1",age:100 },
    {name: "name2",age:101}
    ]
```

How do I do with crossfilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do this with Crossfilter. Easiest option is probably to use Array.map to create a new array with just the fields you want:

```
var data = [
  {name: "name1",age:100,gender: m ,someotherfiled: ""},
  {name: "name2",age:101 ,gender: f,someotherfiled: ""}
];

var newData = data.map(function(d) { return { name: d.name, age: d.age }; });
```